# Determining application server at runtime?

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish, weblogic

Can I determine, during runtime, on which application server my application is deployed: GlassFish, WebLogic or JBoss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using

```
String serverInfo = application.getServerInfo();
```

in a JSP. In a Servlet, try using

```
String serverInfo = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
```